# Google Apps support

Tags: google-workspace

I wanted to register my domain for Google Apps (personal use).

Somehow the registration didn't work, but since then my domain is in "verification process". If there's a problem with that, I should contact Google Apps support. 
My problem is, I can't find an email adress or something to contact the support.
The help forums haven't been very helpful.

Any hints?

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93595

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=contacting_support.html), it seems e-mail and phone support is only available to the Business and Education editions of Google Apps. The only other option available is "online"...

I found [this page](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1071480) which might offer a solution for your problem, or at least a starting point. If not, I suppose you'll have to [ask a new question](http://www.google.com/support/forum/signup?hl=nl&url=/support/forum/ask?hl=nl) in their support system.

Comment: Unfortunately the hints in the mentioned page don't work, because the registration process wasn't completed and so there's no account information.